# Error when enabling react/jsx-sort-props [Rules of eslint-plugin-react]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, next.js, eslint

I`m trying to sort props names alphabetically in my project using the plugin [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react).

I've read the [jsx-sort-props rules option example](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-sort-props.md) and I'm here asking myself: What's props should be used in the `<enable>` field?

```
...
"react/jsx-sort-props": [<enabled>, {
  "callbacksLast": <boolean>,
  "shorthandFirst": <boolean>,
  "shorthandLast": <boolean>,
  "multiline": "ignore" | "first" | "last",
  "ignoreCase": <boolean>,
  "noSortAlphabetically": <boolean>,
  "reservedFirst": <boolean>|<array<string>>,
}]
...
```

I've tried everything but always get an invalid configuration notification:

```
*Error: ESLint configuration in .eslintrc.JSON is invalid: Unexpected top-level property "react/jsx-sort-props".*
```

I'm editing it at my `.eslintrc.json` file:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "next/core-web-vitals"
  ],

  "react/jsx-sort-props": [<enabled>, {
    "callbacksLast": true,
    "shorthandFirst": false,
    "shorthandLast": true,
    "multiline": "last",
    "ignoreCase": true,
    "noSortAlphabetically": false,
    "reservedFirst": false
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your rules into the `rules` property of the object, not into the top level of the object:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "next/core-web-vitals"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-sort-props": [<enabled>, {
```

This helps clearly delimit the difference between ESLint configuration settings and rules - otherwise, the overlap would be confusing, and if there were ever a rule whose name conflicted with a possible other top-level property, there'd be problems.

Comment: I've updated my `.eslintrc.json`  and now I caught a new error saying that my config is invalid for rule "react/jsx-sort-props" . What I'm missing?

See this related topic: [Invalid configuration for rule "react/jsx-sort-props"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71117382/invalid-configuration-for-rule-react-jsx-sort-props)

Comment: Did you find either of the answers useful? Remember when an answer solves your problem, you may consider upvoting or accepting it.