# Invalid configuration for rule "react/jsx-sort-props"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, eslint

I'm trying to sort props names alphabetically using the plugin [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react) but I'm getting this error:

```
[Error ] .eslintrc.json: Configuration for rule "react/jsx-sort-props" is invalid: Value {"callbacksLast":true,"shorthandFirst":false,"shorthandLast":true,"multiline":"last","ignoreCase":true,"noSortAlphabetically":false} should NOT have additional properties.
```

This is my `.eslintrc.json` file:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "next/core-web-vitals"
  ],

  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-sort-props": [
      "2",
      {
        "callbacksLast": true,
        "shorthandFirst": false,
        "shorthandLast": true,
        "multiline": "last",
        "ignoreCase": true,
        "noSortAlphabetically": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues:

- The severity option, if you're using a number, should be a number, not a string that contains a number - `2`, not `"2"`. (Though, personally, I'd suggest using `"error"` instead - it makes it clearer from reading the config what the rule means for your project - `"error"` makes more intuitive sense than `2`)
- There is a bug in the linter rule's `jsx-sort-props.js` - although the docs reference a `multiline` property, said property does not exist anywhere in the lint rule implementation, and so an error is thrown when you pass in an object containing that property. Remove it.

```
"rules": {
    "react/jsx-sort-props": [
        2,
        {
            "callbacksLast": true,
            "shorthandFirst": false,
            "shorthandLast": true,
            "ignoreCase": true,
            "noSortAlphabetically": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `multiline` support was added in `v7.29.0`: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/releases/tag/v7.29.0